# Tizen web app upload warning

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to upload Tizen Web app on the seller store. In the Upload New Binary section, when I try to upload .wgt file it gives me Warning :

`If no screen size is specified in a binary file, display devices cannot be recommended. Make sure that you have specified the screen size to display an application in IDE.`

I have specified 
`tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all` in features section. I have also tried with `screen.size.normal` , but it gives me same error. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

So you have tried this line of code on config.xml file,right? :

```
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
```

Please check out this post here:

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/general-support/specify-screen-size-tizen-store-upload?langswitch=ko

It shed some light on similar error.

Comment: The funny thing is that when you add the features through the IDE the "http://" is omitted, yet it doesn't work without the "http://"